# Which Identity provider I need to use for SAML artifact binding

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, identity, artifact

I am using OKTA and jump cloud but neither have support for SAML artifact binding. Can any one suggest a provider for SAML artifact binding?

Answer (score 0):

The Shibboleth Identity Provider supports SAML2 and SAML1 artifact binding.

More at https://www.shibboleth.net/products/